# Creating Dictionary Value Based on Startswith

Tags: python, list, loops, web-scraping

How can I separate lists into one dictionary based on whether it starts with an letter or number?

```
webscrape1= ['Owner1','Owner2', 'Owner3', '555 Address Street',]

webscrape2 = ['Owner1','555 Address Street',]

webscrape3 = ['Owner1','Owner2', 'Owner3', 'Owner4', 'Owner5',  '555 Address Street',]
```

An attribute error occurs if I try:

```
address = address[1:].startswith(('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'))
```

Comment: Assuming address is last element in list you could use. `webscrape1[-1]` to retrieve address

Comment: `{'Owner' : 'Owner1', 'Owner2', 'Owner3',` this is incorrect notation - you can not have it

Comment: I would go back and look at how the data is being scraped. Improve the output of the scraper before writing complex parsers to interpret the output.

Comment: You can have the owners in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the expected result:

```
d = {"Owner" : [], "Address" : []}
for el in webscrape:
    if el.startswith(('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')):
        d["Address"].append(el)
    else:
        d["Owner"].append(el)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the code that your list always contains the address at the last index of the list. So you can directly fetch that using the `webscrape[-1]` statement and to fetch all the owners simply index from the beginning to the second last element. `webscrape[0:webscrape.length-1]`.